# tor hidden_services on linux live usb

Tags: linux, kali-linux, live-usb, tor

I want to set up an apache2 server on a Linux live USB and run it on Tor.

I have no problem with apache2 but I have problem with Tor.

Because I'm running Tor, I changed the /etc/tor/torrc file to set the ports to the darknet.

My directory on /var/lib/tor/ is empty

I can't find the folder hidden_service/hostname as usual, when I'm running Tor on installed Linux and not in live USB

I tried Mint 18 and newest Kali

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ok guys, the problem is solved

i just figured out that the directory /hidden_service/hostname does not exist
until you edit the /etc/tor/torrc file and decomment the lines about hidden_services,
so when modify the /etc/tor/torrc file to set your hidden_services and then make restart tor or reload,then it creates your hostname and your keys